# JMeter - Assert based on percentile

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter

I know JMeter have some custom properties that store 90, 95 and 99 percentile (if I'm not wrong, aggregate_rpt_pct1, 2 and 3 respectively).

My question is: Is there any assertion where I can retrieve this property to validate against a expected value? Currently I'm running locally, but will have it running on Azure Devops eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's achievable with vanilla JMeter, you can consider using [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) tool as a wrapper for your JMeter test.

Taurus provides flexible and powerful [Pass/Fail Criteria subsystem](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) where you can define the percentiles either for separate sampler/transaction labels or for the overall tests and if it exceeds the defined threshold - Taurus will return [non-zero exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) so Azure Devops pipeline will fail automatically.